# why use double pointer when single pointer can do the work in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, double-pointer

I understand the benefit of using pointer but double pointer is what I really don't understand. I was told that double pointer is used when you want the method to modify the value of param you pass in. Given the example below, `5` will be printed in log. Then why should we use double pointers in `void changeInt(int **i)`?

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int *a = 1;

    changeInt(&a);
    NSLog(@"%i", a);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}

void changeInt(int *i)
{
    *i = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a double pointer with a *scalar* (int). Obviously all you need is a pointer.

But an *object* already *is* a pointer. So to do the same thing with an object, you need a double pointer. The typical use case is `NSError**`:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
                      encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
                         error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: See my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#_pointer_parameters_and_the_address_operator

Comment: oooo, you are my life saver. I've been wondering why single pointer isnt enough. `But an object already is a pointer` clears out all the confusion I have. thank you so much!